# Ajax Request Special characters Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, special-characters

I've been experiencing some trouble with french (or special) characters in IE.
I am trying to load an eform into an iframe. 
The tool I'm working on (internal tool) adds the following meta tag:
"meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=edge"

The code seems to be working fine in chrome and firefox:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url : 'therighturl', // correct url in real code
    dataType: 'text',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=ISO-8859-1",
    beforeSend : function(xhr) {
      xhr.overrideMimeType('text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1');
        },success : function(data){
        $('#eform').html('<br />' + data);
      }
    });
});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've included the code in the question for you.  Please do this in the future, as questions are supposed to be self-contained.

Comment: Thanks Daedalus, I'll keep it in mind ;-)